# Prime divisors of a Babylonian sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Consider the *odd* natural number sequence (see [OEIS A001601](https://oeis.org/A001601)):
$$ S_0 = 3 \\
S_{k+1} = 2S_k^2 - 1 $$

These are *numerators* of reduced rational approximations to $\sqrt 2$ generated by the usual Newton iterations  starting at $1$. Knuth's paper "Ancient Babylonian Algorithms" (Comm. of the ACM, 1972) sets out a case that cuneiform tablets from "about 1800 - 1600 B.C." depict a *sexagesimal floating-point* implementation of this method for extracting square roots.

$$ 1, \frac{1+\frac{2}{1}}{2} = \frac{3}{2}, \frac{\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{3/2}}{2} = \frac{17}{12}, \; \ldots $$

> Two conjectures about the prime divisors of these numerators arise from [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688583/on-a-similar-recurrence-to-the-lucas-lehmer-test-the-variation-involving-the-mu):
>
> 1. Each $S_k$ is square-free.
> 2. For $k\ge 1$ all prime divisors of $S_k$ are congruent to $1 \bmod 4$.

A proof of these conjectures will immediately imply two similar conjectures posed in that previous Question, which references a "modified Lucas-Lehmer sequence" of *even* numbers.  (See also [OEIS A003423](https://oeis.org/A003423).)

**NB:** Somos suggested that Conjecture 2 is implied by Conjecture 1.  In discussing the circle of ideas to verify this, an outright proof of Conjecture 2 was found.  It is briefly sketched in the CW Answer appended below.  At present the computational evidence supports the strengthened but unproven:

> 2'. For $k\ge 1$ all prime divisors of $S_k$ are congruent to $1 \bmod 2^{k+3}$.

**Low hanging fruit**

Because a great deal is known about [prime divisors of Fibonacci numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103037560), my initial expectation was that there would be considerable research relevant to the conjectures posed above.  For the first conjecture, square-freeness of the entries, the only related material I found was this previous MSE Question, involving a different initial condition:

[Search square factors in Lucas–Lehmer sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/search-square-factors-in-lucas-lehmer-sequence)

There David Speyer supplies a heuristic estimate that the number of terms that *are not square-free* is finite and "pretty small".

Regarding the second conjecture, there are two easy partial observations.  Certainly $S_k$ itself is $1 \bmod 4$ for each $k\ge 1$ as the induction argument shows (basis $S_1 = 17$):

$$ S_{k+1} \equiv 2 S_k^2 - 1 \equiv 2\cdot 1 - 1 \equiv 1 \bmod 4 $$

A similar argument shows that the terms $S_k$ are pairwise coprime.  Let $p$ be a prime that divides $S_k$, i.e. $S_k \equiv 0 \bmod p$.  Then:

$$ S_{k+1} \equiv 2 S_k^2 - 1 \equiv -1 \bmod p $$

and thereafter (by induction for $j \gt 1$):

$$ S_{k+j} \equiv 2 - 1 \equiv 1 \bmod p $$

Evidently $p$ will not divide any entry subsequent to $S_k$, so those entries are coprime to $S_k$.  (We didn't use primality of $p$, only that $p\gt 1$, but it was enough to establish coprimality of the $S_k$.)

**Computational evidence**

Faced with a paucity of theoretical results, we can always hope that just factoring the entries $S_k$ for $k\ge 1$ may quickly give a negative result, either by turning up a square factor or a prime factor congruent to $3 \bmod 4$.  But this has not been the case.

The initial entry $S_0=3$ and the next three are primes:

$$ \begin{aligned}
S_1 &= 17 \\
S_2 &= 577 \\
S_3 &= 665857 \end{aligned} $$

Indeed those latter prime entries $S_k$ are congruent to $1 \bmod 2^{k+3}$.

The next five entries (spaced into six digit blocks for easier reading) are composite and have been fully factored:

$$ \begin{aligned}
S_4 &= 886731\,088897 \\
       &= 257 \cdot 1409 \cdot 2\,448769 \\
S_5 &= 1\,572584\,048032\,918633\,353217 \\
       &= 11777 \cdot 2\,393857 \cdot 55\,780318\,173953 \\
S_6 &= 4\,946041\,176255\,201878\,775086\,487573\,351061\,418968\,498177 \\
       &= 7681 \cdot 1\,492993 \cdot 431\,302713\,980890\,947612\,633357\,964569\,696769 \\
S_7 &= \mathbf{C}98 = 7460\,967982\,148609  \cdot  \mathbf{P}82 \\
S_8 &= \mathbf{C}196 = 79873 \cdot 719073\,884161 \cdot \mathbf{P}66 \cdot \mathbf{P}114
\end{aligned} $$

The digit lengths of entries $S_k$ increase rapidly, at least doubling with each step.  For the last entry above we've used an abbreviation scheme common in factoring large numbers, indicating a composite number with $\mathbf C$ and a prime number with $\mathbf P$, followed respectively by the number of digits needed.

So far the prime factors of these $S_k$ all satisfy the strengthened Conjecture $2'$ of congruence to $1 \bmod 2^{k+3}$.

This is increasingly a "hard row to hoe," computationally speaking, but there is an alternative approach that finds all the prime divisors of this Babylonian sequence up to a moderate limit, say less than a million, with considerably less effort. This and other partial results will be collected in a CW Answer below.

Comment: @Somos: It would be nice to connect the two conjectures, but we only need an even number of factors of the form $4k+3$ to get a product of the form $4k+1$, e.g. $7\cdot 11=4 (19)+1$.

Comment: Ouch! Of course.

Comment: @Somos: But if we knew something more about the entries, your suggestion would be apt.  If not only congruent to $1 \bmod 4$, the $S_k$ were a sum of two squares, then [any prime factors congruent to $3 \bmod 4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) would have to appear as even powers.  Thus Conjecture 1 would imply Conjecture 2, as you wished.

Comment: See recent [OEIS sequence 307372](https://oeis.org/A307372) for sum of squares.

Comment: @Somos: Amazingly it seems your suggestion has busted the problem open.  A little scratch work shows that indeed $S_k = T_k^2 + 1$, where $T_1 = 4$ and thereafter, $T_k = 2S_{k-2}T_{k-1}$.  So each $S_k$ is a sum of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

**A closed form solution**

The terms $S_k$ are iterates of the second degree Tchebychev polynomial (of the first kind):

$$ f(x) = 2x^2 - 1$$

with initial value $3$.  It follows that:

$$ S_k = \cosh (2^k \cosh^{-1} 3) $$

as outlined in answer to [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564378/rational-sequence-with-a-n1-2a-n2-1) or [this other Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896184/general-term-of-sequence-a-0-2-and-a-n1-2a-n2-1).  Sadly this explicit solution seems to be  useless for our purposes.

**A product formula for entries**

For $k\ge 1$ we show by induction:

$$ S_{k+1} = \left[ 4^{k+2} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} S_i^2 \right] + 1 $$

Indeed if we adopt the usual convention that an empty product is $1$, then this hold for $k=0$ as well.  The first few terms, $k=0,1,2$ , serve as our basis step:

$$ \begin{aligned} S_1 &= 4^2\cdot 1 + 1 = 17 \\
S_2 &= 4^3 \cdot S_0^2 + 1 = 577 \\
S_3 &= 4^4 (S_0 \cdot S_1)^2 + 1 = 665857 \end{aligned} $$

The induction step can be taken as follows:

$$ \begin{aligned} S_{k+2} &= 2S_{k+1}^2 -1 \\
&= 2\left( 2S_k^2 - 1 \right) S_{k+1} - 1 \\
&= 4 S_k^2 S_{k+1} - 2 S_{k+1} - 1 \\
&= 4 S_k^2 \left(4^{k+2} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} S_i^2 + 1 \right) - 2\left(2S_k^2 - 1\right) - 1 \\
&= \left[4^{k+3} \prod_{i=0}^k S_i^2\right] + 4S_k^2 - 4S_k^2 + 2 - 1 \\
&= \left[4^{k+3} \prod_{i=0}^k S_i^2\right] + 1 \end{aligned} $$

Note that the induction hypothesis is used here only once, applied to $k$ on our way to establishing the case $k+1$.  The other identities used are the sequence's defining relations $S_{k+1} = 2S_k^2 - 1$.

**Coprimality of terms revisited**

Using the product formula above gives more precise information about the coprimality of terms in the sequence:

$$ \begin{aligned}
S_{k+1} &\equiv -1 \bmod S_k^2 \\
S_{k+1} &\equiv +1 \bmod S_j^2 \text{ for } 0\le j \lt k 
\end{aligned} $$

The first of these follows from the defining relation of the sequence, and the second follows from the product formula established above.

**Proof of Conjecture 2**

The product formula above says that for $k \ge 1$, $S_k$ is of the form $n^2 + 1$.  It follows that modulo any prime divisor $p$ of such $S_k$, $-1$ is a quadratic residue.  Thus any [odd prime divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4) $p$ will be congruent to $1 \bmod 4$.   See also [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552556/proof-by-contradiction-let-n-in-mathbbn-any-odd-prime-factor-p-of-n2).

**Strengthening Conjecture 2**

For $k\ge 1$, the prime divisors of $S_k$ are actually congruent to $1\bmod 8$, a slight strengthening of Conjecture 2.  Given that prime $p$ divides $S_k = 2S_k^2 - 1$,  it must be that $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.  Then the second supplement to the law of quadratic reciprocity implies $p$ is either congruent to $\pm 1 \bmod 8$.  Only $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ is consistent with  $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Empirically for prime divisors $p$ of $S_k$ the top power of $2$ that divides $p-1$ grows with increasing $k$, as the following table summarizes:

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
 k & \text{prime?} & S_k \text{ prime factors } p \\ \hline
1 & \text{yes} & 2^4 + 1 \\ \hline
2 & \text{yes} & 2^6 3^2 + 1 \\ \hline
3 & \text{yes} & 2^8 3^2 17^2 + 1 \\ \hline
4 & \text{no} & (2^8+1)(2^7\cdot 11 + 1)(2^7\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 911 + 1) \\ \hline
5 & \text{no} & (2^9\cdot 23+1)(2^8 3^2\cdot 1039 + 1)(2^8\cdot 3041\cdot 5147\cdot 13921 + 1) \\ \hline
6 & \text{no} & \begin{array}{c}(2^9\cdot 3\cdot 5 +1)(2^{11}3^6 +1)\\(2^9\cdot 3\cdot 7^3\cdot 13\cdot 263\cdot 2147503\cdot 111497203601498327476613 +1)\end{array} \\ \hline
7 & \text{no} & \begin{array}{c} (2^{10}\cdot 7286101545067 + 1)\\(2^{10}\cdot 
11\cdot 197\cdot 14268312047910853080882581\cdot 207118459764708621027403333949253228941663842143239 +1)\end{array} \\ \hline
8 & \text{no} & \begin{array}{c} (2^{11}\cdot 3\cdot 13 + 1)(2^{11}\cdot 3^4\cdot 5\cdot 23\cdot 37693 + 1) \\
(2^{11}\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 31 \\ \cdot 146895790987891709799980308411 454666755530685063771873467473 + 1) \\
(2^{11}\cdot 3\cdot 53 \cdot 97 \cdot 197 \\ 
\cdot 438921501503783941728573362042998675569676958777 \\ \cdot  700769597973643172674517472532110991945276879083466747+ 1)\end{array} \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

This suggests more can be said about congruence of such $p$ mod higher powers of two.